# How to add years in DateTime field in php symfony2 doctrine2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have this as expiry date

`$expiryDate = new DateTime();`

But that puts expiry date to today time. How can i add 5 years in that time

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check [DateTime::modify](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php)

```
$expiryDate->modify('+5 year');
```

or

```
$expiryDate = new DateTime('+5 year');
```

Comment: how can i put in constructor. cuurent use this in my constructor `$expiryDate = new DateTime();` Can i do something like `$expiryDate = new DateTime(+5 year);`